# event to know when each view in a multiple view page has been loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app with multiple views being loaded in that app. I want to know how each of the views can broadcast on event to say that its views has been loaded.

I have a base route :-

```
  $stateProvider.state('root-profile', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            '@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/base-profile/base-profile-view.html',
                controller: 'baseProfileController'
            },
            'header@root-profile': {
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/header-profile/header-profile-view.html',
                controller: 'headerProfileController'
            },
            'leftSideBar@root-profile': {
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/sidebar/left/left-side-bar-view.html',
                controller: 'leftSideBarController'
            },
            'rightSideBar@root-profile': {
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/sidebar/right/right-side-bar-view.html',
                controller: 'rightSideBarController'
            },
            'footer@root-profile': {
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/footer-profile/footer-profile-view.html',
                controller: 'footerProfileController'
            }

        } //END views
    }); //END state
```

My routing is as shown above. Is it possible to know when each of the following views has been loaded. I thought of each controller in the view to broadcast and event, but the problem is that how to know if that specific view has been loaded or not. By loaded i mean its view has been loaded.

Comment: From @Rahul I can use `Is there a way to know which view has been loaded from "data" parameter.  

    this.$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
    });` in each of my controllers, but is there a way to know which view has been loaded from that snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
 $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
   //Here your view content is fully loaded !!
 });
```

Comment: Eumm if i add that in the baseProfileController, it will be called 6 times, first --> when baseProfile is loaded, second --> when header loaded, third --> left loaded, fourth --> right loaded , fifth --> footer loaded, sixth --> once again for the base view to be loaded, so this can be a solution but i will have to add the snippet you've give to each one of my controller and then broadcast a loaded event and catch that in base controller and after the footer has given its broadcast it will mean everything is loaded